# Android App that could reproduce NFC card wave

Tags: android, mobile, nfc, smart-card

**SCENARIO:** In Switzerland we have a pass card that is used for:

- city public transport
- trains
- ski pass
- public parking
- etc...

it's called SwissPass:

[image]

**PROBLEM:** I park my car into a public parking and I need the SwissPass in order to open the gate of the parking. Sometimes I forget my SwissPass at home so I have to go back home to pick up the card in order to open the gate.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** Ideally I would like to have an Android App that could read the NFC wave emitted by my SwissPass and could reproduce it.

I know for sure that modern telephones can read the [NFC wave of a passport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tananaev.passportreader&hl=en_US).

I need something like a [card wallet](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=card%20wallet&c=apps&hl=en&gl=US) but I cannot find a card wallet that could reproduce the wave of a card.

Comment: Usually such cards are not simple NFC-ID cards which only send their identifier and can be cloned easily, instead they are more like Smartcards with NFC-interface. You will have to wait for an official SwissCard wallet app. Note that reading a NFC card and emulating the same is something totally different.

Comment: Thank you. You can post this as an answer if you want.